# VPS Git vs custom git service

Tags: git, svn, repository, vps

Is there any reason I should pay for a custom git service like unfuddled or bitbucket, something to that extent? I have a vps I'm paying $5 a month for 50 gb of storage space, and it just doesn't seem cost effective to pay another 10-15 for a git repository with 2gb of storage space. Does it take up a lot of ram, cpu cycles or disk space that they cover for you?  Is it just difficult to set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just more complicated to set everything up. There is no single "Git server" – you get to configure SSH and user accounts and ACLs for pushing, `git-daemon` for anonymous pull, a web server & *cgit* if you want a web interface, another part of the web server for HTTP pull/push...

Tools like Gitolite and Gitosis help **a lot**, though, by automatically configuring all necessary components. (It's a bit easier with Hg, which uses HTTP as its primary protocol and has a built-in web interface. [*Not to be interpreted as a suggestion to use Hg.*])

GitHub and BitBucket also give you various other features such as a bug tracker, simple website hosting, "pull requests" and other community features, as well as certain reliability guarantees.

Do note that both GitHub and BitBucket (as well as other services such as Gitorious and repo.or.cz) offer **free** hosting of public repositories. In BitBucket, private ones are free too.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket is free, even for private repositories.

Hence:

> Is there any reason I should pay for a custom git service like unfuddled or bitbucket, something to that extent?

No.

> Does it take up a lot of ram, cpu cycles or disk space that they cover for you?

It might, depending on your usage.

> Is it just difficult to set up?

It's slightly annoying to set up the git software, but what those git providers give you is a collaboration platform, way beyond what git is -- they have a lot of value-add that can justify payments. E.g. I consider github the better of the two services, because it can really improve the collaboration between developers, when there are more than one develop in the project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's good to know too! I'll keep that in mind when setting up a repository.